# Nvidia Driver Won't Update (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, upgrade

Whenever I update my system though the Update Manager, the Nvidia driver doesn't update. It gives me the following errors:
(Also See Attached Photos)
If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

**My PC Details:**

**OS:** Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

**GPU:** GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2080 Super WINDFORCE OC 8G Graphics Card

**An error occurred:**

E: /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450-server_450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-450.102.04-key-documentation', which is also in package libnvidia-common-450 450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

**Details:**

(Reading database ... 649608 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-common-450-server_450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-common-450-server (450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450-server_450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-450.102.04-key-documentation', which is also in package libnvidia-common-450 450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450-server_450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the problem. I put this command in the terminal, and then re-installed the updates. And the Nvidia Driver updated properly:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f libnvidia-common-450-server
```